# Android send xml file doesn't send attachment

Tags: android, email, android-intent

I've seen several exemples but still don't get why, when I'm editing the mail I see the .xml attached but when I receive ther's no attachment!

Here is my code

```
File f = new File("data/data/xxx/files/xxx.xml");
                    Boolean b1 = f.exists();
                    Boolean b2 = f.canRead();
                       if (b1 && b2) {
                          Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                          sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                          sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "");
                          sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" +
                             f.getAbsolutePath()));
                          sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "XXX");
                          sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, R.string.mail_body);
                          startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Email:"));
                       } else {
...
```

Ah, only a detail...when I choose the app to send there is no subject or body, even if I wrote putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT) and putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT), but that's a detail...

Edit: I just debuged my intent: it says "NOT CACHED" in value of the stream, how to solve it?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can't attach a file from internal storage directly for some security purpose, hence first you have to copy that file from internal to external directory and then mail after that if you want you can delete that file from external storage in onActivityResult() method.

Here's a code :

```
private  File copyFileToExternal(String fileName) {
        File file = null;
        String newPath = Environment.getExternalStorageState()+"/folderName/";
        try {
            File f = new File(newPath);
            f.mkdirs();
            FileInputStream fin = openFileInput(fileName);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newPath + fileName);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len1 = 0;
            while ((len1 = fin.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
            }
            fin.close();
            fos.close();
            file = new File(newPath + fileName);
            if (file.exists())
                return file;
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return null;
    }
```

Method to Email:

```
private void sendEmail(String email) {

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageState()+"/folderName/" + fileName+ ".xml");
        Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("application/octet-stream");
        intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        String to[] = { email };
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send mail..."),
                1222);
    }
```

and then

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 1222) {
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageState()+"/folderName/" + fileName+ ".xml");
            file.delete();
}
}
```

Call this method like this:

```
 copyFileToExternal(filename + ".xml");
 sendEmail(EmailId);
```

Comment: How do you assign the `onActivityResult` callback to `startActivityForResult`?

Comment: @JoshPinter old question, but in case you still need an answer: the `onActivityResult` callback is a framework callback that's part of `Activity`. It automatically gets called when the `Activity` that is started by `startActivityForResult` returns/finishes, and it returns the arbitrary code that he used "1222". He didn't make the methods, but actually @Override them.

Comment: I suspect that getExternalStorageState should be getExternalStorageDirectory. Also, openFileInput is a method on Context, so if you're putting this method in a Fragment or other class that doesn't extend Context, you'll need to pass a Context to call openFileInput.

Comment: can we retrieve this database in same app using other device with data ?

Answer (score 1):

> I've seen several exemples but still don't get why, when I'm editing the mail I see the .xml attached but when I receive ther's no attachment!

First, third-party apps cannot read internal storage of your app.

Second, that might not be the right path to internal storage of your app. **Never hardcode paths**. Your app will fail for secondary accounts and restricted profiles on Android 4.2 tablets, for example. Always use a method, like `getFilesDir()`, to get at your portion of internal storage.

You will need to either copy your file to external storage, or better yet, [use `FileProvider` to serve up your file from internal storage](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) via a `content://` `Uri`.

Comment: It actually is the right path. And also When I created the file I used FileOutputStream fileOS = c.openFileOutput(FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE); that I belive, gives others apps the right to read my app data, isn't right?

Comment: @Michele: "It actually is the right path" -- not for all devices and all users. "that I belive, gives others apps the right to read my app data, isn't right?" -- it should. Your `Uri` is also malformed, because you hardcoded a path, then turned around and screwed up the string concatenation. Use `getFileStreamPath(FILE_NAME)` to get the `File`, then use `Uri.fromFile()` to reliably generate a `Uri` pointing to this file. You are better served using `FileProvider`, because you can limit read access to this file to this one `startActivity()` call, rather than letting anyone access the file.

Comment: Yes that seems to me better, I'll try this way :)